# Is it possible to append images to div using HTML5 form in different HTML5 file and save new DOM permantently on web-server using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Suppose I have 2 HTML files. One called Image_Input_Form.html and the other called Image_Slider.html.

The Image_Input_Form.html contains a form to adds images to an image slider in Image_Slider.html.

**Image_Input_Form.html**

```
 <form>
  IMAGE: <input type="text" name="imagename"><br>
 </form>
```

The **Image_Slider.html** file harbors a div with slider-images (and code not shown here to run the slider.)

```
 <div class="slideshow">
 <img src="../../img/java1.gif">
 <img src="../../img/java2.gif">
 <img src="../../img/java3.gif">
 <img src="../../img/java4.gif">
 </div>
```

I then want to append new slides via the form to the slideshow-div.
Probably something like this with jQuery:

```
   $( ".slideshow" ).append( "<img src="../../img/java5.gif">" );
```

The goal is to change the DOM of Image_Slider.html with additional images and save Image_Slider.html permanently on the web-server.

Is that possible ? OR IS THERE A COMPLETELY DIFFERENT APPROACH TO REACH THAT GOAL (without PHP).

Comment: You can send the HTML to a server using JS, but definitely you'd need some server side language to save the file.

Comment: i dont think you can accomplish anything like this without a server-side language

Comment: Modify markup in JavaScript + saving it to the server = xss security hole. Yeah, you can do it, but you shouldn't. To save the file in the server you'll need some server side program to do that, like scripts or doing some ftp hacks. And without PHP, yes, with Java or other language that you like.